# Adobe Flash Builder http data service call fails only after export

Tags: flash, http, adobe, builder

I wrote an app using adobe flash builder that makes an http data service call to a website.

When I build and launch the app it loads in my browser (the address in the broswer is C:\Users\path\to\my\app.html) and works perfectly.  However, when I upload the app to my website or even launch it from outside the project build directory, the HTTP service call fails with the popup

```
Security error accessing url
Destination: DefaultHTTP
```

Of course I googled this error and realized it may have something to do with a 'crossdomain.xml' in my web root directory.  I tried this and it continued to fail.
Below was my crossite domain file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>       
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">  
<cross-domain-policy>       
    <allow-access-from domain="www.my_domain_for_http_service.com" />       
</cross-domain-policy>
```

I'm using the free trial version of Adobe flash builder, but I do not see anything indicating that this has to do with the error.

Any thoughts?  Data from http service call is in xml format.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may be using two different Flash Players.  FB will use a debugger version, but your browser may be using the regular download.  Right-click on the Flash when it is running, and see what you can find.

If they are different, then the security setting may also be different.  You might have to allow Flash access to the remote website.  This can also be accessed via the right-click menu while hovering over the Flash app.